# Query returns 0 in row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an app with user registration. I have problem whenever I fill the fields with something, the result only shows 0 as records. Also I have a validation function for checking if some mail is already used, and the next problem is even if I type a new name and email to insert in database, it shows that its already used in database.

```
public function findUserByEmail($email) {
    $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
      // Bind value
    $this->db->bind(':email', $email);
    $row = $this->db->single();
      // Check row
    if($this->db->rowCount() > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know what `$this->db` is so we're not going to be able to help out much.

Comment: Also, phpmyadmin is a web interface to your database, not the database itself.

Comment: Is `bind()` a valid method in PDO? I thought it had t be either `bindParam()` or `bindValue()`

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: You're doing `SELECT *` when you don't care about the values. A better solution is `SELECT COUNT(*)` and then test if that count is 0 or non-zero. The user record could contain a lot of data that you fetch and then immediately discard which is a wasteful practice.

Answer (score -1):

You're preparing a query, you're binding values, but are you sure you're executing the query? This is the form I'd expect to see if using a prepared statement:

```
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
  $stmt->execute([ ':email' => $email ]);
```